# RAILS: What is the expected concurrent visitor limits for 16CPU & 30GB VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Today I have prepared a digital marketing campaing which increased the number of visitors to my site suddenly. My site responsiveness became degregaded and when I check the CPU & Mem Allocations, I have seen that unicorn workers are eating all the CPU resources. At this time, when I checked from google analytics I have seen that there were 170 concurrent visitors on my site. (Rails 5.2.1 with Postgresql, Nginx & Unicorn)

My questions are;

1. In a typical ecommerce app, what might be the expected concurrent user capacity for my HW? (AWS c4.4xlarge = 16vCPU + 30GB RAM)
2. How can I make detailed analysis to understand which part of my application needs to be tuned for better performance?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this question is suitable for SO since there isn't a clear answer. It's extremely difficult to answer without having detailed access to your app/code.
I'm also not sure that there is a "typical ecommerce app". Your app's performances depends a lots on the way your database is setup, the way your queries are written etc.

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with any of the services mentioned below, and there are probably alternatives that I'm not aware of.

That being said, you can use a tool like [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/) or [Scout](https://scoutapp.com/) to find expensive queries and slow controller methods.